# Href in Wordpress 4.1.6 and jQuery > 2.0.0 not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

On my Wordpress 4.1.6 using jQuery 3.1.1, I am not able to get the href in my nav menu to work. The console says:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.example.no/wordpress#home  jquery-3.1.1.min.js?ver=3.1.1:2
```

..when clicking the link produced from this code:

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>#<?php echo $menu_id ?>">
<?php echo $menu_item->title  ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

..the browser says:

```
http://www.example.com/wordpress/#http://www.example.com/wordpress/#home
```

..while the source code actually says:

```
http://www.example.com/wordpress/#home
```

When testing with other jQuery versions I figured that I manage to get the href to work, if I am using jQuery <= 2.0.0, but I cannot do this because other functions on my site needs a greater jQuery version.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Show Your jQuery code

Comment: The `site_url()` function isn't by default followed by a forward slash, I think that's the problem.

Comment: You are right, the slash was missing. I added: `<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/#<?php echo $menu_id ?>">` but error is same with slash:
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.example.no/wordpress/#home`

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 for navbar!